# MySQL How to join multiple sets of data and columns into a Single table

Tags: mysql

> > I am having trouble understanding the structure of the query i wish to perform. What i have is a large set of data in a table with multiple UnitID's. The units have temperatures and Timestamps of when the temperatures where recorded.
> >
> > I want to be able to display the data where I can see the Average temperature of each unit separated in a weekly interval.

---

---

Apologies for my previous post, I'm still a novice with querying. But i will show you what i have done so far.

```
SELECT UnitID AS 'Truck ID',  
AVG(Temp) As 'AVG Temp',  
LogTime AS 'Event Time',  
DAY(g.`LogTime`) as 'Day',  
MONTH(g.`LogTime`) as 'Month',  
COUNT(*) AS 'Count'  
FROM `temperature` as g  
WHERE  DATE_SUB(g.`LogTime`,INTERVAL 1 WEEK)  
AND Ana > 13  AND Ana < 16 AND NOT g.Temp = -100  
GROUP BY 'truck id', YEAR(g.`LogTime`),MONTH(g.`LogTime`),WEEK(g.`LogTime`)
Order BY 'truck id', YEAR(g.`LogTime`),MONTH(g.`LogTime`),WEEK(g.`LogTime`)  
;
```

(Sorry, I don't know how to display a table result at the moment)

This result gives me the weekly temperature averages of a truck, and shows me on which day of the month the temperature was recorded, as well as a count of temperatures per week, per truck.

The Query I want to perform , creates 5 columns, being UnitID, Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4.
Within the 'Week' columns I want to be able to display a weekly(Every day of the Week) temperature average for each truck, where the following week is set a week after the previous week (ie. Week2 is set to display the avg(temp) one week from Week1).

And this is where I am stuck on the structure of how to create the query. Im not sure if i need to create sub-queries or use a Union clause. I have tried a couple of queries , but i have deleted them because they did not work. I'm not sure if this query is too complex or if its even possible.

If anyone will be able to help I would greatly appreciate it. If there is any other info I can supply that will help, I will try to do so.

Hopefully this is solvable. :p

Comment: We help those, who help themselves and your question shows no evidence of you trying anything to solve your issue.

Comment: Please clarify weekly... S,M,T,W,R,F or week 1,2,3,4...53...?  looks like you'll need to use [DayOfWeek or WeekOfYear, or maybe yearWeek](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html) AVG, and group by unit and whatever week function you're after.  Good questions yield good answers, poor ones yield many comments/questions.  Good questions consist of structure, sample data, expected results, and what has been tried.

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried, so that we can help you to understand what is missing

Comment: Sorry about not showing enough info, I hope my question is better structured

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a `WEEK` function that will return the week of the year as an integer (0-52). You can use that in you `GROUP BY` clause, and then use the `AVG` aggregation function to get the average temperature. Your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT unitID, WEEK(dateColumn) AS week, AVG(tempColumn) AS averageTemperature
FROM myTable
GROUP BY unitID, WEEK(dateColumn);
```

Here is a list of other helpful [Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) that may be useful for querying your database.

Comment: Thank you for the post. Is there any way to use those queries combined in a way to display the data where i can see weekly temperature averages for each unitID ?

Comment: @user5070140 isn't that what this query does?

Comment: this query does show the average temperature every week for a truck, but I am trying to display the weeks in columns to the right so that the unitid isnt repeated in rows. If that makes sense :p